# Convergence of Newton's method at a root

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

Let $f(x)$ have an $m^{th}$ root at $r$.

Consider Newton's method: $x_{i+1}=x_i-\frac{mf(x_i)}{f'(x_i)}$.

Why does it have quadratic convergence?

Comment: For $f \in C^2$?

Comment: $f \in C^{m+1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to find the root of the function $f(x)^\frac1m$. Let $g(x)$=$f(x)^\frac1m$.
Then the iteration step to approximate the roots of $g(x)$ would be 
$$x_{i+1} = x_i - \frac{g(x_i)}{g'(x_i)}$$
Substitute $f(x)^\frac1m$ again in place of $g(x)$ and you'd get your answer.
For the explanation of the quadratic convergence part , the wikipedia article is pretty clear about it.

Comment: thx! you are so clever.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this site](http://cavern.uark.edu/~arnold/4363/Newtons.pdf), it can give you a better explanation.